# NEST Update Document containing a Deletion

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

my Question is the following. Ive got a Datatype which consists of a Dictionary.

```
Data d = new Data();
d.Id = "1"
d.Items.Add("item1", "hello");
d.Items.Add("item2", "world");
```

Now I want to delete the Item with the key *item1*.

```
d.Items.Remove("item1");
Index.Update(d);
```

My Update Method looks like this:

```
client.Update<Data>(u => u
            .Index("defaultindex")
            .Type("data")
            .Document(d)
            .Id(d.Id)
            .RetryOnConflict(5)
            .Refresh()
            );
```

But the Item with the key *item1* still remains. Does anyone know, how I can tell the update Method to delete this entry?

Answer (score 2):

The Update can happen either via a Script or via an Updated Document. In your case you are updating via the document option, but you are specifying the script type in your call, because you are using `Update<T>` and not `Update<T,K>`. You can see an example of the script update in the [Nest Update by Script API](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/update.html).

Try changing your code to the following and you should see this update as you are expecting.

```
client.Update<Data, Data>(u => u
            .Index("defaultindex")
            .Type("data")
            .Document(d)
            .Id(d.Id)
            .RetryOnConflict(5)
            .Refresh()
            );
```

You can even just send a partial update and only update the `Items` section.

```
var updateDocument = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
var newItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();
newItems.Add("item2","world");
updateDocument.Items = newItems;

client.Update<Data, object>(u => u
            .Index("defaultindex")
            .Type("data")
            .Document(updateDocument)
            .Id(d.Id)
            .RetryOnConflict(5)
            .Refresh()
            );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the fast answer. I tried both(the complete and partial one) but both still fail :(

Comment: I just updated the second example, realized I missed an important part. If that still does not work, I am out of ideas, as this is what I am using with success.

Comment: No, still not working, could there be a wrong setting in the mapping or something, which could be the reason?